# preventing existing users to login to a site collection in office365

Tags: office-365, security

I have an environment where I know that external users have access to some sites, and I want to trim this access for existing users. I need to verify if going to central administration and in the sharing section, will turning off the sharing prevent users from accessing my environment? Is there a way to stop existing users from accessing the sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocking the option in Office 365 from SharePoint admin center will do it. It will prevent inviting more people as well as cut off the access for existing ones.